# Generic factory function with constraints and default parameter erroring with TS2322

Tags: typescript

I have some kind of base class...

```js
class BaseClass<ItemType> {
    // Irrelevant parameters elided for simplicity...
    constructor(__items: Iterable<ItemType>) {}
}
```

and I want a factory that can return instances of that class or some subclass, which will supply some values for the elided parameters.The caller can supply the constructor of the subclass it wants constructed with those parameters, so let's declare an interface...

```js
export interface GenericConstructorInterface<S, T extends BaseClass<S>> {
    new(items: Iterable<S>): T;
}
```

and now we can declare the factory...

```js
// This works...
export function factory<A, B extends BaseClass<A>>(__items: Iterable<A>, subclassConstructor: GenericConstructorInterface<A, B>): B {
    return new subclassConstructor(__items);
}
```

but, say I don't want to condemn all callers to having to provide the constructor function, so I try

```js
// The default parameter won't typecheck:
// Type 'typeof BaseClass' is not assignable to type 'GenericConstructorInterface<A, B>'.
// Type 'BaseClass<A>' is not assignable to type 'B'.ts(2322)
export function factory<A, B extends BaseClass<A>>(__items: Iterable<A>, subclassConstructor: GenericConstructorInterface<A, B> = BaseClass): B {
    return new subclassConstructor(__items);
}
```

and now the default parameter doesn't typecheck. What have I misunderstood  here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any default parameter would have to be compatible with all possible type parameters. Since `subclassConstructor` is dependent on `B`, the class `BaseClass` will not be valid as a default for any `B` passed in. (`B` could be `DerivedFromBaseClass` so `BaseClass` will not be a valid default for `subclassConstructor`).

You could use a type assertion in the default parameter value, although a better option would be to use multiple overloads. Like this the caller can't pass in a `B` that is inconsistent with the default:

```
class BaseClass<ItemType> {
    constructor(__items: Iterable<ItemType>) {}
}

export interface GenericConstructorInterface<S, T extends BaseClass<S>> {
    new(items: Iterable<S>): T;
}

export function factory2<A>(__items: Iterable<A>): BaseClass<A>
export function factory2<A, B extends BaseClass<A>>(__items: Iterable<A>, subclassConstructor: GenericConstructorInterface<A, B>): B 
export function factory2<A>(__items: Iterable<A>, subclassConstructor: GenericConstructorInterface<A, BaseClass<A>> = BaseClass): BaseClass<A> {
    return new subclassConstructor(__items);
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks so much. I was stumped as to why i was convinced it should infer B as BaseClass, focusing too much on the types at the definition site, forgetting the bigger picture of the types at call-sites.